# Excel: Referencing a cell using a function

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, vba

I hope i can explain this clearly, I am trying to compile data and the machine that i get the data from has 7 rows in between the values I need. Therefore to compile I write:

```
Cell1 = A13 - B13
Cell2 = A13(+7) - B13(+7) = A20 - B20
Cell3 = A20(+7) - B20(+7) = A27 - B27
Etc.....
```

Is there a way to write a reference using a function? In this case: A(x+7)

Note: In this example the B column is just a "control value" that I have to subtract from A which is my "sample value"

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, but functions like `Indirect`, `Offset`, `Index` are probably directly relevant for a non-VBA approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,13+((ROW(1:1)-1)*7))-INDEX(B:B,13+((ROW(1:1)-1)*7))
```

And copy down as need be.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for this answer (6 years ago lol) it saved me a ton of time. The time has come yet again for me to compile data using an index function, and again I'm unable to figure it out. This time, I need to pull every 18th column. How do I re-write this function in order to automatically change the column instead of row? I've tried it every which way and I just cant get it to work.  Thank you!

Comment: The `13`s in the formula are the start row of the data.  And the `7`s are the spacing.  Try to adjust with that information.  If you are unable, please write up a new question.  You can link back to this answer for reference.  But asking a new question on an old one is not proper for this site.