# Using INDEX to pull periodic columns out of a separate sheet

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I have a set of data that is WAY too big. I want to pull out every 18th column and put it into a new sheet that will be easier to manage. This is the code I have now, which is based on a similar question asking about pulling out cells from a row: [Excel: Referencing a cell using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433280/excel-referencing-a-cell-using-a-function/36433359#36433359)

```
=INDEX(Sheet4!A+((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*18),Sheet4!1:1)
```

I am currently getting a #NAME? error

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry: `=INDEX(Sheet4!1:1,1+((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*18))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks so much, you're my savior!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dynamic array to avoid requiring copying across and down:

```
=LET(data, Sheet4!$A$1:$ZZ$1000, lastrow, MAX((LEN(data)>0)*ROW(data)), arr, INDEX(data, SEQUENCE(lastrow), 1+(SEQUENCE(,5,0))*18), IF(arr=0,"",arr))
```

where the three values (excluding 0 which is the sequence start value) in: `1+(SEQUENCE(,5,0))*18` control starting column, number of columns to spill and the column frequency in that order.